# Batch Script to rename a particular logfile and move it to a new location.

Tags: batch-rename

I want to  write a Batch Script to rename a particular logfile and move it to a new location. This script would be set as a daily job for a logfile that is generated once the job runs. Can anyone Help me .

Thanks 
Anantha

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, to see if it works, but you are looking for something similar, I assume:

```
ren file.old file.new
move /y file.new c:\location
```